# How to get my variable works as a variable and not a property of object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

here is the deal

```
   if(!userExist) {
          userJson["user"] = [{"name": msg.author.username, "commands": { userCommand : userCommandValue }}]
    }
```

**edit:**
to avoid confusion, this is my userCommand :

let userCommand = msg.content;

**userCommand** is considered like a **property** and not like a **variable** existing...

Is there a way to bypass that ?

Comment: userCommand is a property in ur code

Comment: userCommand is definied like this in my code :
let userCommand = msg.content;

Comment: You want to treat the `userCommand` property as a variable? You'll have to "access" the `userCommand` property in the `userJSON["user"]` object and manually assign it to a variable.

Comment: Ah, judging by your latest comment I'm off the mark. This question is a little confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of ES6, your can do this: wrap a `[]` arount `userCommand`

```js
if(!userExist) {
      userJson["user"] = [{"name": msg.author.username, "commands": { [userCommand] : userCommandValue }}]
}
```

Comment: and this feature is called _computed property_.

Comment: My man ! thank you so much !